# Python create new column in dataframe by pairing existing rows with lists as values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe of lists that looks something like this.

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |

I would like to create a new column that looks something like this:

| Index | Value | Value_y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B | C |
| 2 | A,B | D |
| 3 | C | D |

For some reason, I was unable to place the square parenthesis in the columns. But they are lists.

Essentially, I would like the new dataframe to have values as unique pairs. I understand that there is a way to do this if the columns do not contain lists as values, but since my values are lists, they are unhashable. Is there a way to do this should the columns contain lists? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi palutuna, why don't you convert the lists, eg convert the lists to strings... Does the dataframe rely on lists to work?

Comment: So, IIUC, there are three unique pairs from your original dataframe: (A,B and C), (A,B and D), and (C and D)?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew yes, that is correct. [A,B] , [C] , and [D] are lists.

Comment: @Lunar thank you for your suggestion. Yes unfortunately, the dataframe relies on lists to work. This is because later on, I will have to iterate through the elements within the list for each row. I was perhaps thinking of converting them to strings first, before pairing the rows and then converting them back to lists, but I am unsure how feasible it is.

Comment: I have updated my code, is this what you were thinking about?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew hi Kevin, yes that was indeed what I was thinking of. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `combinations` from `itertools` to help you with this.

```
from itertools import combinations

data = {'value':[['A','B'],['C'],['D']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(df.value.tolist(), 2)), columns = ['Value', 'Value_y'])

new_df
Out[57]: 
    Value Value_y
0  [A, B]     [C]
1  [A, B]     [D]
2     [C]     [D]
```